# Python strip()'s strange behavior with print and stdout.write during file operation

Tags: python

In the below code, the print statement though terminated with comma to suppress newline printing and having strip() to get rid of newline char in the file's input line still produces newline where as in sys.stdout.write() the strip works fine, knocks off the trailing newline char from file input. So why this dual behavior of strip()? or from where the newline is coming in the print statement?

```
h = open('file')
print h.readline().strip(),
sys.stdout.write(h.readline().strip())
```

Comment: Are you running this on the Python console, or is this in a file? Also, which version of Python are you using.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my PC. I do not get any kind of space between the result of `print` and `sys.stdout.write`. This is probably a tricky situation where the soft-space plays a role. I'd suggest to use `from __future__ import print_function` and use the `print` as a function just like in python3.

Comment: There is no "dual behaviour of strip". Please include a *complete* example that we can run and that demonstrates the problem. Without one the question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: Print always adds a newline for me, even with comma. Write never does. Where is the behaviour of using comma to suppress newline documented?

Comment: I am using Python version 2.6.8, yes I am running it as a python script file. Actually I missed to mention that we need to comment out either of the lines below the first line. Then you will get to know the difference what I am talking about.

Comment: `cat file`
output:
a b c
d e f

`h = open('file')
print h.readline().strip(),`
output:
a b c
$ # shell prompt in self contained line

`h = open('file')
sys.stdout.write(h.readline().strip())`
output:
a b c$ # no new line in the output, shell prompt starts atonce


`h = open('file')
print h.readline().strip(),
sys.stdout.write(h.readline().strip())`
a b cd e f$

Answer (score 0):

> So why this dual behavior of strip()?

There is no "dual behaviour of `strip()`". It behaves exactly the same regardless of context.

> from where the newline is coming in the print statement?

It seems pretty certain that the `print` statement in your snippet does not output a new line. If you are observing one, it almost certainly comes from elsewhere.

**However, do make sure that you're running your script using a (non-interactive) interpreter. An interactive console could treat trailing commas in `print` differently.**

Answer (score 0):

"sys.stdout.write()" is only used to get rid of **"\n"** in string, but it can't delete the **spaces** in the end or the front of string.(e.g: "   string   ").
so the strip() method is used to delete the spaces in the second parameter of print.